# iOS XCode native vs PhoneGap for speed of development

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, html, cordova

I'm aiming to do an app like Badoo:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/meet-new-people-chat-socialize/id351331194?mt=8

Basically it involves chatting with people and GPS geo-location.

Question is - I have two options:

A. Have this developed in native XCode for iOS

OR

B. Have this developed in HTML5 + PhoneGap

Assuming either route is with an experienced developer, how much time does B save over route A in terms of getting a viable product out?

Performance， speed, and UI are all important for this, so obviously native is ideal... but how much time would PhoneGap save in getting it out?

Thanks so much！

Comment: Assuming cross-platforming is not important for the moment. I'm focused on iOS first.

Comment: For this kind of App, I vote for Option A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have this developed in PhoneGap, as you can target multiple platforms. And also phonegap also supports geo location functionality. so its a win win with phonegap.

if you are going to target ONE platform, do the Xcode route. if you are going to target android and ios together, then please Phonegap.

Comment: but with an app like this where speed of texting and UX is very important, how much of a difference do you feel Phonegap would produce compared to xcode？ Would the UX and perfomance efficiency be much different? My ideal is like Kik or Line's UX for efficiency. thanks guys!

Comment: Using Phonegap will also make it easier for people to rip you off... [Link](http://www.tuaw.com/2012/02/17/ripoff-apps-plague-some-ios-developers/)

Comment: Hi. The speed is not affected by phonegap, if it ever is, its negligible. For testing, any sort of html verifying site or even dreamweaver can do that for you. You just have to create the coding tests. For UX, its really a experience and very very subjective and varies from person to person. But strongly i feel that the original questionare needs to decide on what platforms they will target.

Comment: But roughly, how much time would developing it in phonegap vs xcode save?

Comment: Hi. If you are building for iPhone/iPad (JUST IOS), then xcode will be your best friend and it will be much faster to develop in xcode in that case, as documentation and sites like this one (stack over flow) have many code snippets around and it will make your life easier. And not to mention that storyboards are also excellent in making your User interface.

Comment: xrave, there is no way to put a hard number to time saved.  It depends on the complexity of the app you want to build, as well as the skills of the person doing development.  All anyone can do is give you a very rough estimate of percentage saved as they have....

Answer (score 2):

I'm a fan of native development even if you are deploying to multiple platforms.

However, the main point is if you have skills in html/css/javascript and potentially want to support multiple platforms then by all means go with PhoneGap.

If you have skills in iOS development then go native and reconsider what to do if you want to support other platforms later.

IMO, once you've developed an application in one language, then the amount of effort required to do another version in Android, PhoneGap, or whatever is greatly reduced.  If you know the target platform well it is painting by numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are building for iPhone/iPad (JUST IOS), then xcode will be your best friend and it will be much faster to develop in xcode in that case, as documentation and sites like this one (stack over flow) have many code snippets around and it will make your life easier. And not to mention that storyboards are also excellent in making your User interface. If you take the xcode route, it will still take you roughly the same amount of time as phonegap.

HOWEVER, if you want to make the SAME app for iphone and android, then phonegap will save you 50% project time, and this only applies when you are talking about one app for both android and iphone

Just out of curiosity, where do your skills lie in? ios or html/css?